# Autofac: Dispose of created services not called when exception is thrown by later service creation

Tags: c#, autofac

I have the following, minimal example to reproduce an issue of my real life application:

```cs
public class ServiceA : IStartable, IDisposable {
    public required ServiceB ServiceB { get; set; }
    
    public void Start() {
        ServiceB.Connect();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Console.WriteLine("ServiceA disposed");
    }
}

public class ServiceB : IDisposable {
    public void Connect() {
        throw new TimeoutException();
    }
    
    public void Dispose() {
        Console.WriteLine("ServiceB disposed");
    }
}
```

and a console application:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType(typeof(ServiceA)).AsSelf().As<IStartable>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType(typeof(ServiceB)).AsSelf().InstancePerDependency();

var container = builder.Build();

Console.ReadKey();

container.Dispose();

Console.ReadKey();
```

From dependency chain ServiceB is a dependency of ServiceA and, therfore, is instanciated first on Build(). During Start() of ServiceA, Connect() on ServiceB is called which throws an Exception. The Exception is forwared to Build() which fails and the container is not created.

My expectation reading Autofac docs:

> Automatic Disposal
> To take advantage of automatic deterministic disposal, your component must implement IDisposable. You can then register your component as needed and at the end of each lifetime scope in which the component is resolved, the Dispose() method on the component will be called.

would be, that Dipose() on created ServiceB is called. This is not the case. ServiceB lives somewhere in my application and I cannot dispose it as IContainer was not created.

ChatGPT suggest to catch the exception and call Dispose() on IContainer later. This would mean, I need to check if Connect() on ServiceB was successfull (property bool IsConnected) and if not, I call Dispose().

Of course, this would solve my issue. But again, my expecation was, that Autofac is handling this for me via LifetimeScope.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting edge case around the use of `IStartable`. I would recommend:

1. [**File an issue** about that.](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues)
2. **Update the title of your question** to reflect that this is pretty specifically about `IStartable` - the title of the question currently ("Autofac: Dispose of created services not called when exception is thrown by later service creation") is pretty misleading. It's not just *any ol' service*, it's very specifically around things that get auto-instantiated at container build. This will help other people with similar issues find your question later.

On a side note, I see that you're doing the setting using a *required property* rather than a *constructor parameter*. Technically speaking, you don't actually have to populate a required parameter to construct an object - `required` is syntactic compiler sugar, not guidance to object activation.

More specifically:

```cs
// This won't work, it'll be caught by the compiler:
new ServiceA();

// But this totally works:
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ServiceA));
```

You should be aware of that distinction because not all DI frameworks will set required properties for you. For example, I don't think the MS DI framework will currently do that. If something is *truly required*, you should make it a constructor parameter even though that can sometimes get messy.